# L2TP VPN Tunnel from Mac to Windows

Tags: windows, vpn

I want to connect from my Mac to Windows VPN server. VPN server requires EAP-MSCHAP v2 authentication protocol (Windows proprietary) but I didn't found this protocol in MacOS VPN settings. Is there some way to establish L2TP VPN connection with EAP-MSCHAP v2 from Mac to Windows?

VPN settings required for connection:
L2TP(preshared key for auth) + EAP-MSCHAP v2 + PPP settings: enabled LCP extensions and Enabled software compression. Also, I pinned screenshots with working example of VPN tunnel setting on my Windows machine.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Apple says create a profile via your MDM solution https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/deployment/dep5d180f86a/web  I think you do need someway of creating a profile to load onto macOS - possible via Apple Configurator (don't really know).